# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have looked through this site and cannot find a similar scenario. I am trying to run the following code

```
SELECT st.storeid, s.noofitems
FROM salestrnsaction AS st, soldvia AS s
WHERE st.tid = s.tid
ORDER BY noofitems ASC;
```

and am still receiving the 'SQL command not properly ended' error.

More specifically, this is the message I am receiving.

```
SELECT st.storeid, s.noofitems
FROM salestrnsaction AS st, soldvia AS s
WHERE st.tid = s.tid
ORDER BY noofitems ASC
Error at Command Line : 287 Column : 22
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using ORACLE right?Using `AS` in alias in FROM Clause is not valid in Oracle.
Please refrain from using AS in giving aliases to tables.

Just write the alias after the table.

```
SELECT st.storeid, s.noofitems
FROM salestrnsaction st, soldvia s
WHERE st.tid = s.tid
ORDER BY s.noofitems ASC;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. We haven't covered aliases yet, so I was going off of what I could find online. This worked. Appreciate the help all.

Comment: Np.If it works, please mark it as the correct answer.Thanks

Comment: Do we need to mandatorly use `alias`in `order by`? @brenners1302

Comment: yes.so it wouldnt be ambigous if the column exist in both tables.

Comment: This was my problem, stupid oracle.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a little bit different.  I was just performing a simple `SELECT` and got the same error.

```
SELECT *
-- Inventory
FROM EQUIPMENT as EQP
```

What I discovered from the research I did is the `AS` is not needed for Oracle SQL vs MySQL, so when I changed to the query to...

```
SELECT *
-- Inventory
FROM EQUIPMENT EQP
```

this eliminated the error.